# many views which inherit from templateview

Tags: django, django-templates

I have two views which inherit from templateview and which requires a login through required_login.
It's simple when I created the views separately:

```
class AboutView(TemplateView):   
    template_name = 'app1/about.html'

    @method_decorator(login_required)                          
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):                       
        return super(AboutView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

class HelpView(TemplateView):   
    template_name = 'app1/help.html'

    @method_decorator(login_required)                          
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):                       
        return super(HelpView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

This does work. The question is Why doesn't the code below work

```
class StaticTemplateView(TemplateView):                        
    @method_decorator(login_required)                          
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):                       
        return super(AboutView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)


class AboutView(StaticTemplateView):                           
    template_name = 'app1/about.html'                        


class HelpView(StaticTemplateView):                            
    template_name = 'app1/help.html'
```

Error here:

```
super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the error lies in the copy/paste :)

Instead:

```
return super(AboutView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Try this:

```
return super(StaticTemplateView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```